# Does Hotspot Shield VPN actually work?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn

In using **Hotspot Shield VPN** free I get two different IP addresses. One is my actual IP address shown on Speedtest.net through Firefox, but through Chrome it shows a different one.  Does this mean I am not really using a VPN?

Comment: Are either of them your actual IP address?

Comment: Yes, when I use Firefox it shows my actual IP address. When I click on Test protection in the Hotspot Shield menu, it brings up a web page showing me a different IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from such malware/buzzword software.

Buy a proper VPN subscription and use OpenVPN or SSTP.
OpenVPN is available for almost any platform and is more reliable with flaky connections.
SSTP is available on modern Windows systems.